# ValidationSummary does not show errors in a jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, requiredfieldvalidator, asp.net-validators

I want to show validation errors in dialog box.

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
     if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
         $("#errorDisplay").dialog({
             title: "Validation Error",
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             width: 250,
             buttons: {
                 Close: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
</script>
```

I have the following `GridView` fragment with controls to validate:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBins" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="true"
    PageSize="10" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle"
    EnableTheming="False" onsorting="gvBins_Sorting" 
    onpageindexchanging="gvBins_PageIndexChanging" 
    onpageindexchanged="gvBins_PageIndexChanged" 
    onselectedindexchanged="gvBins_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    onsorted="gvBins_Sorted" onrowcancelingedit="gvBins_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowediting="gvBins_RowEditing" onrowupdating="gvBins_RowUpdating"
    onrowdatabound="gvBins_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="odd" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="ui-state-default" Height="40px" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager-row" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="ui-state-default" Height="40px" />
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bin" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" SortExpression="Bin" HeaderStyle-CssClass="binGridHeader" FooterStyle-CssClass="binGridFooter">
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblBin" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BinNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblBinEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BinNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddBin" runat="server" Width="70%" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Bin is missing" ControlToValidate="txtAddBin" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Bin Entered" ControlToValidate="txtAddBin" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{6}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
       </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" SortExpression="Currency" HeaderStyle-CssClass="binGridHeader" FooterStyle-CssClass="binGridFooter">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Currency") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditCurrency" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnDataBinding="ddlCurrencyCodes_OnDataBinding" >
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtBinEditCurrency" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Need to Select Currency" ControlToValidate="ddlEditCurrency" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinUpdate">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddCurrency" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnDataBinding="ddlCurrencyCodes_OnDataBinding" >
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Need to Select Currency" ControlToValidate="ddlAddCurrency" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

And I have the following validation summary control:

```
<div id="errorDisplay" style="display: none">
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" id="validationSummary"></asp:ValidationSummary>
</div>
```

When I fail validation, my dialog box is showing together with `*` for required and regular expression validators.
However, `Error Message` text is not displayed in the dialog.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see where you're changing display:none; when an error is triggered. That inline style has precedence over other styles. have your tried it without?

Comment: Yes, I did try it. I have exactly the same validation on another page, and it works. The only difference between controls is that here controls belong to a validation group